# Compile-time plugin / Automated Factory Registration with separate modules constraint

Tags: c++

(re-stated by the author to make it more clear).

Yes, another *Automated Factory Registration* question. But I have new (maybe too ambitious) constraints. I work for a big (human brain) project and need to make the image I/O module extensible. This is the pipeline I would like to implement:

1. a developer writes its own image I/O plugin according to a simple Factory-based API.
2. he/she is not allowed to modify my code.
3. he/she puts the source files in a *plugins* folder I created for this purpose.
4. he/she launches cmake and compiles the whole project. CMake will automatically discover the new files and include them in the project.
5. at pre-`main()` time, the new plugin class is discovered and registered to the Factory automatically.
6. in the `main()`, I can do

   ```
   Base* b = Factory::create("DerivedClass");  
   b->dosomething();
   ```

Here's my proposal, which mixes previous work and suggestions found on the web. But it doesn't work, unless the plugin's header is included in `main.cpp`, which breaks the requirement 2.

**`ImageFormat.h`**

```
class Format
{
    public:

        virtual std::string id() const = 0;
        virtual void dosomething() = 0;
        virtual ~Format() {}
};

typedef Format* (*PluginCreator)(void);

class FormatFactory
{
    private:

        std::map<std::string, PluginCreator> registry;  //map of registered plugins

    public:

        static FormatFactory* instance()
        {
            static FormatFactory* uniqueInstance = new FormatFactory();
            return uniqueInstance;
        }

        static std::string registerPlugin(PluginCreator creator, std::string id) 
        {
            instance()->creators[id] = creator;
            return id;
        }

        static Format* create(std::string id) throw (myexception)
        { 
            if(instance()->creators.find(id) == instance()->creators.end())
                throw myexception("Format not found");
            return (instance()->creators[id])(); 
        }
};
```

**`ExampleFormat.h`**

```
class ExampleFormat : public Format 
{
    private:

        static const std::string id;
        static Format* create() { return instance(); }

    public:

        static ExampleFormat* instance(){
            static ExampleFormat* uniqueInstance = new ExampleFormat();
            return uniqueInstance;
        }

        std::string id() const { return id; }

        void dosomething(){"I am an example format and I do pretty cool stuff";}
};


// this should guarantee that the singleton is instantiated. But works only if this header is included in the main.cpp or other modules of the main project.
namespace{
    static const ExampleFormat* object = ExampleFormat::instance();
}
```

**`ExampleFormat.cpp`**

```
#include "ExampleFormat.h"

const std::string ExampleFormat::id = FormatFactory::registerPlugin(&create, "ExampleFormat");
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "ImageFormat.h"

int main()
{
    FormatFactory::create("ExampleFormat")->dosomething();
    return 1;
}
```

Thank you,
Alessandro

Comment: did you think about making your plug-ins dynamic libraries? then the singletons become available at the time you load the library (can make this pre-main by making a plugin-discoverer as a singleton which loads all dynamic libraries in the plugin directory)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: yes we have discussed it and discarded at the moment. Cross-platform portability is a major requirement and we would like to keep this project as portable as possible. DLL-plugins are a great thing (I have developed many) but portability is an issue.

Comment: what you maybe can do is let CMake create a header file which includes all discovered plugins. include this header in your main.cpp and you should be golden.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios. Nice solution, I will definitely try it. Thanks. But it's meta-code generation. I was hoping for a solution to be embedded in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to how I do it. But one difference is that you are assigning to a variable in the class you are registering. I just declare a static global variable in an anonymous namespace.

I believe that your variable is not being created because no instance of your class has been created. Just like static variables in functions are not set until the first time the function is run.

Try using a global variable to register in the factory instead of a class variable.

An example from one of my projects:

```
namespace {
    static RegisterInFactory_2<Reader, Reader_3>
    registerMe_3(
        Reader_3::identifier()
    );
};

const std::string& Reader_3::identifier()
{
    static const std::string id("Reader_3");
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I got your point, even though the code you posted is not 100% clear to me. However, I cannot dirty the global namespace as it's a really big (Human Brain) Project. Furthermore, using a global static variable seems a bit dangerous because of the "static order initialization fiasco" problem. I am looking for a safer (not only working) solution. But it might be I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: @alessandro: The anonymous namespace keeps the global namespace clean enough for my purposes. I don't know if everyone agrees. And I thought you solved the init order problem with a singleton?

Comment: it seems I have something to learn here. You are right about the unnamed namespace. But I would like to fully understand your code. I don't get how the registration works. Could you give more details please? Thanks.

Comment: @alessandro: Well yes there is a factory template which has a constructor and the constructor adds a call to a function that constructs a Reader_3 and returns a pointer to a Reader. I thought it was pretty obvious, it is a lot like the code you posted.

Comment: Yes but now I found another problem. Whatever your solution is based on (singleton+members, static objects, etc.), nothing happens unless the header of the new module (in my case, **ExampleFormat.h**) is included at least one time in the main project. No inclusions -> no usage -> no guarantee that static objects are initialized. And what I see is that both our solutions rely on static initializations. What does matter is _where_ to put this registration+init code, and in my case everything should be put in the new module, which is never included from my side. Any ideas?

Comment: btw, I re-stated the question and made it more clear.